# sorting list of objects by multiple fields with 1.8 jdk

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have collection of persons:

```
class Person {
    public String name;
    public int count;
    public boolean favorite;

    // getters / setters ...
}
```

I want to sort collection of persons by:

1. First display items with favorite=true
2. Second display items with count > 0
3. Last display items with count == 0

How can I write this conditions with Comparator from 1.8 JDK and retrieve expected results?

Comment: Have you tried `Comparator.comparing(...).thenComparing(...)`?

Comment: Also, it's unclear whether you want to filter or sort, and if you want to sort, whether items sorted by criterions 2 and 3 should remain in the original order, or whether you could e.g. also just sort by `count` in descending order.

Comment: What @tobias_k says is true. are you trying to sort your collections or are you trying to display the person objects by conditions? if it's the second answer, a simple for-loop & if-else statements should suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Comparator.comparing(...).thenComparing(...)` to sort by more than one attribute. For sorting favourites first, you can sort by that attribute, but then have to reverse the result, as `false` sorts before `true`. Assuming that you want to sort just by whether the `count` is `> 0`, and not by the actual value of the count:

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("p1", 2, true),
        new Person("p2", 0, false),
        new Person("p3", 0, true),
        new Person("p4", 1, false),
        new Person("p5", 3, true));

persons.stream().sorted(Comparator
            .comparing(Person::isFavorite).reversed()
            .thenComparing(p -> p.getCount() == 0))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Result:

```
Person(name=p1, count=2, favorite=true)
Person(name=p5, count=3, favorite=true)
Person(name=p3, count=0, favorite=true)
Person(name=p4, count=1, favorite=false)
Person(name=p2, count=0, favorite=false)
```

Note that the final `count == 0` condition is redundant (assuming that `count` can not be `< 0`)

Or sort by `count` directly and reverse once at the end; this will sort `p5` before `p1` in the example:

```
persons.stream().sorted(Comparator
            .comparing(Person::isFavorite)
            .thenComparing(Person::getCount).reversed())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to sort your persons and not filter them, you could do the following:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
  ...

  @Override
  int compareTo(Person person)
  {
    // Maye not specified
    if (person == null)
      return (1);

    // Compare 'favorite'
    // Favorites first, so flag=true means smaller
    if (this.favorite && (!person.favorite))
      return (-1);
    else if ((!this.favorite) && person.favorite)
      return (1);

    // Compare 'count'
    // Having count > 0 first, so count=0 means greater
    // Assuming count is never negative
    if ((this.count == 0) && (person.count > 0))
      return (1);
    if ((this.count > 0) && (person.count == 0))
      return (-1);

    // At this point, both persons have the same 'favorite' flag
    // And both have either count=0 or count>0
    // Order by name in that case
    return (this.name.compareTo(person.name));

  } // compareTo

} // class Person
```

After that, sort your persons:

```
List<Person> my_persons;
my_persons = ....
Collections.sort(my_persons);
```

Comment: This solution can done even with java 7 and lower versions. Question was to sort list based on java 8 streams.